# Using @ (at sign) in PHP Laravel strings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing, error-suppression

I have the below code in my app. The problem is the @ (at sign). When it's there, I get syntax highlighting and errors as if the string doesn't end. When remove it, the page works fine (minus the action not existing). I've tried escaping the @ and that doesn't work. I've also tried double quotes, but that doesn't work either. How can I escape @?

I could use the route function and avoid the @ entirely but I feel that the action function is far more clear in terms of what it's doing so I'd rather not use route.

```
@extends('layouts.default') <?php
$url = URL::action('UsersController@index'); ?>

@section('header')
    @include('partials.components.searchHeader', array('title' => "Users", 'results' => $users->getTotal(), 'total' => $total, 'url' => URL::route( 'users.index' ), 'type' => 'user'))
@stop

<?php
if(Auth::user()->isAdmin()) $publishedFellows = Fellow::published()->get();
if(!Auth::user()->isFellow()) $publishedOpportunities = Opportunity::select('opportunities.*')->published()->sortedByCompany()->get(); ?>

@section('content')
    @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        @include('partials.components.add-button', array('url' => '/users/create', 'name' => 'Add User'))
    @endif
    <?php $partialsList = [
        'listItems' => $users,
        'search' => $search,
        'url' => URL::route('users.index'),
        'pills' => $pills,
        'indexView' => 'users.single',
        'type' => 'user',
        'total' => $total,
    ]; ?>
    @include('partials.list')
@stop
```

Comment: just fills the variables in the controller and use it in the template,

Answer (score 1):

To escape `@` symbols in blade - you just use a double `@@`.

So this:

```
@@example
```

will print

```
@example
```

However your code is very messy, and that is probably causing you problems. The biggest issue is you are using `extend` - but then you are putting code inbetween the sections, which is not called correctly. Further - the code you are putting inbetween the sections to save variables is not even been called anywhere!

You should refactor your view to something like this to fix the issue:

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('header')
    @include('partials.components.searchHeader', ['title' => "Users", 'results' => $users->getTotal(), 'total' => $total, 'url' => URL::route( 'users.index' ), 'type' => 'user'])
@stop


@section('content')
    @if(Auth::user()->isAdmin())
        @include('partials.components.add-button', ['url' => '/users/create', 'name' => 'Add User'])
    @endif
    @include('partials.list', ['listItems' => $users, 'search' => $search, 'url' => URL::route('users.index'), 'pills' => $pills, 'indexView' => 'users.single', 'type' => 'user', 'total' => $total])
@stop
```

Comment: My code is not messy. I originally had those ridiculous long lines in my code but that became too unwieldy. The array is looked at immediately within the included view for the needed vars and acts as a kind of namespacing, thus preventing a page from working with a same named var from an earlier file.

Comment: Your problem is the variables are not defined the way you are thinking they are. You need to pass them along to any included files. You cannot just declare variables between `@section` and think it will work - it wont reliably, and your going to run into errors like the ones you are having.

Comment: And you can change the long lines to short ones, that wasnt the bit I was referring to - I'm referring to the multiple declarations of variables scattered randomly throughout your view file.